# For a beginner, is there much difference between MySQL and PostgreSQL

Tags: mysql, database, postgresql

IS there much difference between MySQL and PostgreSQL for a beginner like me, using basic select statements and the like, or are the main differences with using more advanced queries?

Answer (score 51):

The reason why I usually suggest PostgreSQL before MySQL is because MySQL is far from the standards (SQL-wise). It does not support the use of window functions (8.4 version), common table expressions (8.4), **CHECK constraints**, EXCEPT/MINUS operator, even FULL OUTER JOINs... Even though you may have never heard of these words, you'll have to use those concepts at some point.

I strongly suggest you to start with PostgreSQL, then you can learn what "real" SQL is. Then, you can decide if MySQL is sufficient or not.

P.S. I started with MySQL and I regretted it. I now use PostgreSQL and I love it.

Comment: Good, specific information. Performance results are against PostgreSQL, sometimes having a lightweight SQL is a good idea, especially if you don't need the extra bloat, but you want something that's still SQL, rather than go with the NoSQL data storage paradigms

Comment: The myth that MySQL is faster than PostgreSQL has not been true for several years now. Especially since 8.3, PostgreSQL scales better in a high transactional write scenario. And the optimizer is a lot smarter when it comes to complex statements. MySQL with MyISAM might still be faster, then you lose all the advantages of a DBMS like transactions and (foreign key) constraints

Comment: `EXCEPT` is ANSI while `MINUS` is not.  I seldom see the need for a `FULL OUTER JOIN`, which can be reproduced using the more common OUTER joins and UNION.  I'd also point out that you're talking about PostgreSQL 8.4+, being that windowing/analytics are relatively new to PostgreSQL. ** [The biggest reason to me for a beginner to use PostgreSQL would be because of MySQL's hidden column in the GROUP BY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-hidden-columns.html) **

Comment: I know you can simulate FULL OUTER JOIN (and EXCEPT), but the syntax is much clearer when you can use those. You are right about PostgreSQL 8.4, I'll edit my post.

Comment: Wow! we've managed to provide quite a lot of information :) I think the biggest takeaway is that both SQLs really go after different markets, and both are good to know. Whichever you stat with is your preference, whichever you use in the real world depends on your needs (yes, DBMS is neat, sometimes it's an overkill.. See my comment to another answer - a lot of entreprises would use both depending on requirements)

Answer (score 26):

There have already been a lot of great points in favor of PostgreSQL, but I am going to add 1 more:

PostgreSQL has [the best documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/index.html) of any database product I have worked with.

This is why the documentation stands out:

- It actually teaches you the basics of SQL
- It is easy to understand
- It has good examples
- It is very well organized
- It isn't just a feature list with tech notes
- It is all around, well written

Other vendors should be ashamed of what they try and a pass off as documentation.

Comment: Every time I have to go look something up about Sybase, I want to cry and scream. PostgreSQL's documentation is indeed incredible.

Comment: Where is the link to documentation

Comment: @WebDeveloper, have you tried google? It is the first result for "PostreSQL documentation."

Answer (score 9):

While you're just starting out I think you'll appreciate PostgreSQL's pgadminIII GUI tool more than you would those that I've tried for MySQL. This may just be my preference, however.

When you get past the basics you will definitely want to take advantage of PostgreSQL's support of [window functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/interactive/functions-window.html) starting in version 8.4

I'd actually recommend PostgreSQL over MySQL for the window functions alone. Note that there are ways to emulate window functions in MySQL.

Comment: I totall agree. And recursive Common Table Expressions is just another reason to prefer Postgres over MySQL. And the better compliance with the standard... And check constraints... And deferrable constraints...

Comment: And I hate that ctrl-c exits the console in MySQL. In psql it just cancels the current command.

Comment: lack of window function had always bitten me :(

Answer (score 6):

You often hear PostgreSQL enthusiasts argue that it's a "real" RDBMS, while MySQL is not.  This kind of snobbery is dangerous for newcomers, because it comes after years of specific experiences that rub a certain way against a certain personality type.  If you want to approach it in terms of what knowledge would benefit a beginner the most - you're far more likely to find people using MySQL out in the wild than PostgreSQL.  Big sites built around open source software choose MySQL over PostgreSQL by a wide margin.

Personally, I like MySQL because it fits my development style - it just gets stuff done.  I don't use foreign keys.  I *definitely* don't use stored procedures.  But what MySQL does, it does well and it does fast and it does it while giving me a happy "okay, that makes sense" feeling that I don't get with PostgreSQL (I've used both extensively).  There's good community support for MySQL and excellent documentation.  And if you need to do replication (and who doesn't?) MySQL is the clear winner, no questions asked.

There are some things that MySQL lets you do that could possibly lead to bad habits if you switch to less-forgiving databases.  But that's the thing - there's all this talk of how you need to be prepared to jump from RDBMS X to RDBMS Y at a moment's notice.  In my experience, this happens rarely, and when it does there are always quirky differences from one database to the next.  MySQL is different from PostgreSQL, which is different from Oracle, which is different from SQL Server, which is different from sqlite, etc, etc.  I've used all the dbs I listed above, but the one I keep coming back to, the one that gets things done most easily and flexibly for me, is MySQL.

DBAs love to put down MySQL the same way programming language aficionados love to bash PHP - and yet they survive and thrive.  There are reasons for this - they just work, they just get stuff done.  But at the end of the day you should play around with all of it and make up your own mind.

Comment: Could you elaborate on "Just gets things done"? That sounds to me like saying: It's the first thing I came across and have put up with it. I personally use PHP/MySQL because those two words in my mind are associated with one another.

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend PostgreSQL for a beginner as it has far fewer surprises than MySQL.

Here are some of the things that people run into with MySQL:

- http://blog.amber.org/2005/09/27/least-common-denominator/
- http://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=92525
- http://exortech.com/blog/2009/11/30/weekly-release-53-environment-bug-bites/

Meanwhile, PostgreSQL does exactly what you expect it to do in most situations, and usually has a very good reason when it does something unexpected.

Answer (score 3):

PostgreSQL supports more advanced queries, it performs better on complicated queries, but is harder to manage.

MySQL is fast, easy to manage, but you can run into it's limitations on advanced queries, stored procedures and the like.

They are sufficiently similar that I'd recommend starting with MySQL but learning PostgreSQL as well.

Comment: I recently tried the current installer for PostgrSQL 9.0 on Windows. The installation was totally painless and includes the management GUI pgADMIN.

Comment: Yes, but once you're trying to do master/slave replication, clustering.. it gets tricky :( Installation of both MySQL and PostgreSQL is simple, getting it to run efficiently is a pain in the butt. In real applications (I used to run R&D for a large social networking site) there is use for both - we used PostgreSQL for our complicated data (social information, analytics), and we used MySQL for huge repositories of trivial unstructured data (user messages). MySQL replicates and clusters quickly and easily, and is trivial to maintain.