# What's the difference between MySQL and PostreSQL?

Tags: mysql, postgresql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [For a beginner, is there much difference between MySQL and PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4059515/for-a-beginner-is-there-much-difference-between-mysql-and-postgresql)

What is the difference between these two databases? I've only used MySQL before, so sorry if this is an easy question. But, Apple has completed exchanged MySQL for PostreSQL in Lion Server, and no matter where I look, everything supports MySQL, but not PostreSQL. Why? Thanks!

Comment: Who would win in a fight between a gorilla and a shart?

Comment: Well, the real question is then why is MySQL accepted and widely used everywhere? According to that question, PostgreSQL is better. If it is, then why doesn't it dominate?

Comment: There is a [rather lengthy Wiki article](http://www.wikivs.com/wiki/MySQL_vs_PostgreSQL) devoted to this topic.

Comment: @Jack: Take a look at [Why isn't PostgreSQL as widespread as MySQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/404776/why-isnt-postgresql-as-widespread-as-mysql).